# Assign data to levels produced by cut (R)

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a factor variable created with `cut`:

```
mycuts=cut(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),breaks = 3)
mycuts
[1] (0.993,3.33] (0.993,3.33] (0.993,3.33] (3.33,5.67]  (3.33,5.67] 
[6] (5.67,8.01]  (5.67,8.01]  (5.67,8.01] 
Levels: (0.993,3.33] (3.33,5.67] (5.67,8.01]
```

**Now I want distribute vector `otherdata` to the same intervals as `cut` did.**

```
otherdata=c(4,8)
```

A new `cut` always for `otherdata` has levels different from that `data` has, and I can set only labels.

So, I've tried

```
factor(otherdata,levels=levels(mycuts))

[1] <NA> <NA>
Levels: (0.993,3.33] (3.33,5.67] (5.67,8.01]
```

But it does not work.

The desired behaviour (***upd on comment***):

[1] (3.33,5.67] (5.67,8.01]
Levels: (0.993,3.33] (3.33,5.67] (5.67,8.01]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# breaks vector obtained in a way suggested in ?cut
breaks <- unique(as.numeric(c(sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", mycuts), 
                              sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", mycuts))))
cut(c(4, 8), breaks = breaks)
# [1] (3.33,5.67] (5.67,8.01]
# Levels: (0.993,3.33] (3.33,5.67] (5.67,8.01]
```

Comment: No `labs` object defined.

Comment: I accept your answer because it does definitely what was asked!
`cut` default intervals do not agree with min/max values, so I will prefer like  `include.lowest=TRUE` also included.

Answer (score 0):

Just save breaks to a value and reuse them:

```
data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
mn=min(data)
mx=max(data)
d=(mx-mn)/3
br=seq(from=mn,to=mx,by=d)
mycuts=cut(data,breaks = br, include.lowest=TRUE)
otherdata=c(4,8)
cut(otherdata,breaks = br, include.lowest=TRUE)
```